# && in drop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable, logical-operators

I am trying to trigger a `drop` event only on condition that all `draggables` are dropped.

```
drop: function(event,ui){
            var dropd = "#"+ui.draggable.attr("id");
            if("#a_dra" && "#b_dra" && "#c_dra" && "#d_dra" == dropd){
                $("#whistle").get(0).play();
                dfd.resolve();
            };  
        },
```

With this `code` there is a problem. It works when every `div` is dropped and triggers correctly. **Except** when I drop only the `#a_dra` and `#d_dra`, it triggers as well, which is not desirable, since I need it random.

What am I missing in there?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if("#a_dra" && "#b_dra" && "#c_dra" && "#d_dra" == dropd){
```

The above line actually means

```
if(("#a_dra" == true) && ("#b_dra" == true) && ("#c_dra" == true) && ("#d_dra" == dropd)) {
```

You cannot shorthand comparison to multiple values like that.

You can keep state for each draggable that gets dropped, so you can check if all of them have been dropped so that you can resolve your deferred:

```
var dropped = {}

....

drop: function(event,ui){
    var dropd = "#"+ui.draggable.attr("id");
    dropped[dropd] = true;
    if(dropped["#a_dra"] && dropped["#b_dra"] && dropped["#c_dra"] && dropped["#d_dra"]){
        $("#whistle").get(0).play();
        dfd.resolve();
    };  
},
```

Comment: So it should be like `if(("#a_dra" == dropd) && ("#b_dra" == dropd) && ("#c_dra" == dropd) && ("#d_dra" == dropd)) {` ? Because it does not trigger.

Comment: No, that would mean you want `dropd` to be equal to _all_ of those values at the same time. You want `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: But then the `deferred` resolves on the first `drop`. I just can't really wrap my head around this, what would be your suggested syntax then?

Comment: If I only knew what you meant with `var dropped = {}`. :D But it works and I am grateful! :)

Comment: `var dropped = {}` defines a new local variable named `dropped` and initializes it with an empty object (`{}` is an [object literal constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)).

Comment: Well, then it means I still have a lot to learn. Thanks again!